# Can no longer see the crosshair or hotbar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can no longer see the crosshair or the hotbar in Minecraft. How do I turn them back on?

Comment: That + is also called "crosshair" in first person games.

Answer (score 10):

You may have accidentally hit <kbd>F1</kbd>. This key hides the HUD: the crosshair (+ in the middle) and the hotbar (1-9 at the bottom).

If you're on a Mac, you need to hold down <kbd>FN</kbd> then press <kbd>F1</kbd> at the same time, and if you're on a PC you will most likely just press <kbd>F1</kbd>.